# Do I need to keep my PS Plus subscription to play my free PS3 games now that PS Plus is no longer giving away PS3 games?

Tags: ps3, playstation-plus

It has been expressed by Sony that soon PlayStation Plus will no longer be providing PS3 games. I only own a PS3 and not a PS4 so it will become useless to me after this (until I buy another console from them) so I am planning to stop my subscription. Will this still stop me from using my PlayStation Plus obtained games?

I mean PS3 will no longer be a part of PS Plus, why would I need it for games that came from there?

**EDIT** To clarify, I am talking about games that came free with PS Plus, not discounted games I bought using PlayStation Plus discount.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, nothing has changed about the way PS Plus works now that PS3 games are no longer part of the deal.

You won't be able to play the games you got for free once you cancel your PS Plus subscription. However if you re-subscribe at a later date, when you get a PS4 for example, then you will be able to play them again.

Here is the relevant section from the PlayStation website:

> Once your PlayStation Plus membership ends, content you previously downloaded at no cost as part of the membership (such as Plus Monthly Games) will no longer be available. However, free avatars and content you purchased at a discounted PlayStation Plus price is yours to keep.
>
> If your PlayStation Plus membership expires and you renew it at a later date, you will regain access to content that you have previously downloaded through PlayStation Plus.

[Souce](https://www.playstation.com/en-gb/get-help/help-library/playstation-plus/playstation-plus/what-happens-when-your-playstation-plus-membership-is-cancelled/)

Comment: This excerpt was. so far, what I knew. There probably is another question here or other places about this. The big change now is that PS Plus will ,soon, no longer include PS3 games. Which is why I am asking. But I guess as long as nothing else changed, consider the same excerpt as valid, until something does